# What is the point of math research in a third-world country?

Tags: soft-question, advice

When asked about my subject of research ---something related to homological algebra---  by non-mathematicians, the following conversation usually takes place.

--- It would be too complicated to explain it in detail, but my research is about trying to find connections between objects from different branches of mathematics, so as to explain or perhaps  compute one in terms of already known others.

--- What would be the application of this, if any?

--- *We don't know it yet*, but we are hopeful that these various connections and results lead to a deeper understanding of maths that allows a trickle-down effect to open new doors in reality.

An year ago I've got my PhD in Argentina and right now I'm a postdoc abroad. My country is going through a serious economic and social crisis and I can't help but thinking that any money sent to research on homological algebra is not being destined to much more urgent matters. I'd understand it if the research were about an industry-related subject, but... What I do is probably not going to help my country anytime soon. To conclude:

> Why should a third world country invest in abstract mathematical
>   research with no apparent connections to the industry?

Comment: To stop being a third world country...in the more or less long run.

Comment: Not sure this the right site for this sort of question, but I will say this:  there are two questions here. The first is whether anyone ought to be studying certain material and the second is whether $\textit {you}$ should.  These are separate questions.  You might well decide that you can do more good, or achieve greater satisfaction, doing something else.  That doesn't make the study valueless, however.  Good luck to you.

Comment: If you value money more than knowledge your country will always be poor.

Comment: The title question does not match the one in the post. Should a struggling country like Argentina invest (much) into abstract academic research? Probably not. Given that, is there still a point to doing it? Yes. Funding allocation is a matter for governments, not individuals, and individuals can and do devote themselves to higher concerns. Those who believe in what they are doing often do it without funding, for the sake of it, and support themselves by other means (like teaching). And are often kindly remembered by their fellow countrymen nonetheless.

Comment: I fail to see how the question(s) would even be different for a first world country. Tell me how Finland benefits from research in homological algebra.